# Rails - Update Counter Variable when a user shows up as a search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When searching for students and showing results, I want to be able to update a field in the student_metric table to show how many times a student has shown up in search results.

However, every time i run the show routine i get a undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass. Why wont it find the link between the search_student and student_metric table?

**Error**

NoMethodError at /users/1/searches/4
undefined method `searchinclusions' for nil:NilClass

**searches controller**

```
def show
    @search = current_user.searches.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @search.search_students.each do |c|
        c.student_metric.searchinclusions += 1
    end
end
```

search model

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user

    def search_students
        students = StudentProfile.all
        students = students.where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%"]) if name.present?
    return students
    end
end
```

student_profile model

```
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :student_metric, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

student_metric model

```
class StudentMetric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :student_profile
end
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on the error? None of the code shown ever calls `#id`

Comment: Just updated with the error. It should be looping through the array of students and updating the respective search_inclusions holder right?

Comment: Does search_inclusions have an underscore? The code snippet doesn't

Comment: nah it doesnt,       s.integer :searchinclusions

Comment: The problem is that your loop encounters a student which does not have a `search_metric` record associated with it.